# Vim Regex Replace

Tags: regex, vim

I think this is a pretty simple solution but I have been trying to find an answer for about an hour and can't seem to figure it out.

I'm trying to do a find/replace in Vim that would replace a series of numbers that begin with `103` and are followed by four digits to `123` followed by the same four digits, as such:

`1033303` -> `1233303`
`1033213` -> `1233213`

The closest I have come is this:

```
%s/103\d\{4}/123\0/g
```

However this results in the entire number being matched by the `\0`, as such:

`1033303` -> `1231033303`

Thank you very much for any help

Comment: beware chaining regex greediness in vim is weird https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/196/how-to-make-regex-matchers-non-greedy

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You're very close

```
%s/103\(\d\{4}\)/123\1/g
```

The pattern between `\(` and `\)` is a sub-match that can be accessed by `\1`, `\2` etc in the order of appearance. See `:help \(` for more information.

Answer (score 10):

Now w/o the capture group!

```
:%s/103\ze\d\{4}/123/g
```

`\ze` will set the end of the match there. This allows for you match the whole pattern but only do the substitution on a portion of it.

```
:h /\ze
:h /\zs
```

Comment: Would .* after \ze do the trick once everuthing after it os ignored?

Comment: Yes, it would prevent more matches on the same line

Comment: This worked here: `:%s,103\ze.*,123,g` changing delimiter (fast to type) and matching all subsequent chars with `.*` which will be ignored on substitution.

Answer (score 4):

Use a capturing group:

```
%s/103\(\d\{4}\)/123\1/g
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
%s#103\(\d\{4}\)#123\1#g
```